# Toggle close other opened div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to figure out how I can close the other div's when I expand one.

Look at my code here:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( ".faq-question" ).click(function() {
 
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).parent().next('.field-faq-answer').toggle();
 });
 
});
```

```css
.field-faq-answer{
 display:none; 
}
.faq-antwoord{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
 margin-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}
.faq-antwoord p{
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #3395d3;
 margin-left:10px;
}
.field-faq-question-first{
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-container">
    <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
      <h3 class="faq-question">
        Titel 1
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="field-faq-answer">
      <div class="faq-antwoord">
        <p>
          TEST 1
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-container">
    <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
      <h3 class="faq-question">
        Titel 2
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="field-faq-answer">
      <div class="faq-antwoord">
        <p>
          TEST 2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-container">
    <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
      <h3 class="faq-question">
        Titel 3
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="field-faq-answer">
      <div class="faq-antwoord">
        <p>
          TEST 3
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is now possible to click on `titel 1` and `titel 2` and both content will be shown. But I want only want to show 1 answer and hide others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you need to call `hide()` on all other `.field-faq-answer` elements except the one which was clicked, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faq-question").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    var $target = $(this).parent().next('.field-faq-answer').toggle();
    $('.field-faq-answer').not($target).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.field-faq-answer {
  display: none;
}

.faq-antwoord {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.faq-antwoord p {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-left: 2px solid #3395d3;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.field-faq-question-first {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-container">
  <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
    <h3 class="faq-question">
      Titel 1
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="field-faq-answer">
    <div class="faq-antwoord">
      <p>
        TEST 1
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-container">
  <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
    <h3 class="faq-question">
      Titel 2
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="field-faq-answer">
    <div class="faq-antwoord">
      <p>
        TEST 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-container">
  <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
    <h3 class="faq-question">
      Titel 3
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="field-faq-answer">
    <div class="faq-antwoord">
      <p>
        TEST 3
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".faq-question" ).click(function() {

        $('.field-faq-answer').toggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('open'); 
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can target all the other elements, except the ones you're working with, and close those

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var questions = $( ".faq-question" ).on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        questions.not(this).removeClass('open');

        var answer = $(this).parent().next('.field-faq-answer').toggle();
        $('.field-faq-answer').not(answer).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nextAll() method for the parent of parent which is faq-container then use find to select field-FAQ-answer and toggle it.

```
$(this).parent().parent().nextAll('.faq-container').find('.field-faq-answer').toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

 $( ".faq-question" ).click(function() {
  $('.faq-container .field-faq-answer').hide();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
  $(this).parent().next('.field-faq-answer').toggle();
 });
  
 
});
```

```css
.field-faq-answer{
 display:none; 
}
.faq-antwoord{
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
 margin-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:10px;
}
.faq-antwoord p{
 margin-bottom:0px;
 padding-left: 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid #3395d3;
 margin-left:10px;
}
.field-faq-question-first{
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="faq-container">
    <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
      <h3 class="faq-question">
        Titel 1
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="field-faq-answer">
      <div class="faq-antwoord">
        <p>
          TEST 1
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-container">
    <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
      <h3 class="faq-question">
        Titel 2
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="field-faq-answer">
      <div class="faq-antwoord">
        <p>
          TEST 2
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="faq-container">
    <div class="field-faq-question field-faq-question-first">
      <h3 class="faq-question">
        Titel 3
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="field-faq-answer">
      <div class="faq-antwoord">
        <p>
          TEST 3
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it's work try it.